# htaccess & mod_rewrite: display dynamic php page with a folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would want an adress like this:
http://www.domain.com/some_page123/
to display the content of this page: 
http://www.domain.com/script.php?var=some_page123

But i want the URL that appears in the browser to be www.domain.com/some_page123/

Is it possible to do that with htaccess even if the folder "some_page123" doesn't really exist ?

Also, i want to exclude the folder named "infos" from this rewriting. So if an user access the URL www.domain.com/infos/ then it will display the content of "infos" folder. I do NOT want to use script.php rewriting for the folder "infos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /script.php?var=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

add .htacces in your root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^script.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^infos/$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.php?var=$1
```

now I have tested it, it should be working.